# How to adjust div on depending on screen height

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing a software and I have a small problem regarding the `page wrapper div` of the said software. Now what I want is to **adjust the height of the div depending on the height of the screen where it was opened.**

I tried using `percentage(%)` in setting the height but still don't work when opened to other computer that is not the same screensize.

I'm sorry if I couldn't provide you some pictures for i don't have enough to reputation to attach some.

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: usually for percentages to work based on height you need to set `html,body{height:100%}` too

Comment: I usually use percentage on this problem but the parent need also height:100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vh`.

100vh is the height of the screen, you can change the height of an element relative to the height of the screen using vh.

> One unit of the `vh` is 1% of the viewport height. "Viewport" == browser window size == window object. If the viewport is 40cm height, 1vh == 0.4cm.

**Demo**

```css
div {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam unde soluta ex beatae reprehenderit ab repellat nostrum maxime in enim. Enim, reiciendis ducimus eligendi quam iure eius voluptatibus provident facilis?</div>
```

[**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

Read More: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Hello @Tushar thank you so much for the quick response and it really worked! But I used `95vh` since I have a top-nav bar would it affect if I open it in other computer?

Comment: @Ormocanon Depending on how you've added `height` on top nav, if you've used same unit `vh` i.e. `height: 5vh` for top nav, it wont

Comment: And also, would this work in a div inside a div? what I mean here is that if a `parent div` has `53vh` of height (inside body), should I use `100vh` for the `child div` to have the same size as the `parent div`? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ormocanon The position of the element doesn't matter, `vh` will be constant for all, it doesn't depends on parent, you should use `100%` or same `53vh` for inner element

Comment: So if I use `5vh` for the `top-nav` and `95vh` for the `page-wrapper div` It will work in any computer screen size without having a scrollbar? Am I correct @Tushar?